# JHipster tests issues when build

Tags: jhipster

I have a JHIpster application. Now I want to generate a jar. I have this issue when I execute the following command to production

```
./mvnw -Pprod clean verify
```

I receive this error when it starts tests

```
[ERROR] FAIL src/test/javascript/spec/app/entities/cliente/cliente-update.component.spec.ts (109 MB heap size)
[ERROR]   â?? Component Tests â?º Cliente Management Update Component â?º save â?º Should call update service on save for existing entity
[ERROR]
[ERROR]     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)
[ERROR]

[ERROR]
[ERROR]     Difference:
[ERROR]
[ERROR]     - Expected
[ERROR]     + Received
[ERROR]
[ERROR]     - Cliente {
[ERROR]     + Object {
[ERROR]         "bairro": undefined,
[ERROR]         "cancelado": false,
[ERROR]         "cep": undefined
[ERROR]       }
[ERROR]
[ERROR]       41 |
[ERROR]       42 |         // THEN
[ERROR]     > 43 |         expect(service.update).toHaveBeenCalledWith(entity);
[ERROR]          |                                ^
[ERROR]       44 |         expect(comp.isUpdate).toEqual(false);
[ERROR]       45 |       }));
[ERROR]       46 |
[ERROR]
[ERROR]       at testing_1.fakeAsync (src/test/javascript/spec/app/entities/cliente/cliente-update.component.spec.ts:43:32)
[ERROR]       at node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js:793:22
[ERROR]       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:440:160)
[ERROR]       at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:151:35)
[ERROR]       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:440:48)
[ERROR]       at Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:167:37)
[ERROR]       at Object.testBody.length (node_modules/jest-preset-angular/zone-patch/index.js:51:54)
```

It expects a Cliente in `cliente-update.component.spec.ts` but I'm using Cliente instance and not a Object instance

```
describe('save', () => {
      it('Should call update service on save for existing entity', fakeAsync(() => {
        // GIVEN
        const entity = new Cliente(123);
        spyOn(service, 'update').and.returnValue(of(new HttpResponse({ body: entity })));
        comp.updateForm(entity);
        // WHEN
        comp.save();
        tick(); // simulate async

        // THEN
        expect(service.update).toHaveBeenCalledWith(entity);
        expect(comp.isUpdate).toEqual(false);
      }));

      it('Should call create service on save for new entity', fakeAsync(() => {
        // GIVEN
        const entity = new Cliente();
        spyOn(service, 'create').and.returnValue(of(new HttpResponse({ body: entity })));
        comp.updateForm(entity);
        // WHEN
        comp.save();
        tick(); // simulate async

        // THEN
        expect(service.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(entity);
        expect(comp.isUpdate).toEqual(false);
```

When I execute  `./mvnw -Pprod` works normally. How to fix it?

Comment: Did you modify generated code related to this test? Is it the first time you run frontend tests?

Comment: Yeah I've added new fields to Cliente entity and it is my first time using frontend tests in JH

Comment: OK then you got to modify tests accordingly, you can run them using `npm run test` it'll be faster than through maven. A tip that comes too late for you: always run prod builds from day 1 of your JHipster project (ideally using a continuous integration tool) because it runs many more things than a frontend dev build like tests, templates compilation and AOT.